# SSRS 2020 Report Server - ERROR HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable - Resolved...but is there a better way?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating a new production environment using all the newest (server, sql, ssrs).  I got my test environment up and running with no issues but the production environment has MUCH stricter security measures on the network and server.

Just when I thought everything was good I clicked on my first report and got "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable".  Did a few searches and all kinds of related hits popped up.  Trial versions expiring, Duplicate SID's on copied VM's, etc.  But one solution was really easy to test.  Grant the service account used by Reporting Service Local Admin privileges.

Ok...done and it worked!  Easy fix?  But is it the best solution?  What permission does the service account need?  Granting it Admin worked...but is there a lesser (more specific) privilege I can grant to do the same thing?